# SQL Deadlock with keylock (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK) on same object

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I am trying to understand a deadlock caused by 2 stored procedures which are trying to query/update same object in Accounts table. Generally I see 2 keylocks on 2 different associated objects by 2 different processes involved. But in this case, both keylocks are pointing to same associated object which is confusing. Can I get some help to understand this please?

NOTE: The stored procedures are executed in a transaction with serializable isolation level.

```xml
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process_victim" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process_victim" taskpriority="0" logused="6132" waitresource="KEY: 39:72057594582597632 (781c957ed006)" waittime="3279" ownerId="9627380307" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-01-14T15:47:08.737" XDES="0x30091b48428" lockMode="U" schedulerid="16" kpid="224656" status="suspended" spid="665" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2021-01-14T15:47:08.770" lastbatchcompleted="2021-01-14T15:47:08.753" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.753" clientapp="accounts" hostname="2000000" hostpid="13528" loginname="dbUser" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="9627380307" currentdb="39" currentdbname="Trans" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="5716a4fb-ea5f-48ff-bc69-a20036b656f3.dbo.uspInsertMasterAccountTrans" queryhash="0x16139b535590589a" queryplanhash="0x30448d54aa8b7e4c" line="39" stmtstart="2412" stmtend="2708" sqlhandle="0x030027001088596482b8e700aeac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
SELECT  @currentAccountBalance = [ACC].Balance
    FROM [dbo].[Accounts] [ACC]
    WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
    WHERE [ACC].AccountId = @accountId    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 39 Object Id = 1683589136]   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process_other" taskpriority="0" logused="9536" waitresource="KEY: 39:72057594582597632 (ef38eb644a4b)" waittime="3264" ownerId="9627380654" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-01-14T15:47:08.757" XDES="0x30089c80428" lockMode="X" schedulerid="15" kpid="216124" status="suspended" spid="532" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-01-14T15:47:08.783" lastbatchcompleted="2021-01-14T15:47:08.780" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.780" clientapp="accounts" hostname="1000001" hostpid="24452" loginname="dbUser" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="9627380654" currentdb="39" currentdbname="Trans" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="5716a4fb-ea5f-48ff-bc69-a20036b656f3.dbo.uspInsertDebitCashTrans" queryhash="0xe4a5aeeea80cb67b" queryplanhash="0xcbcba51d221c9bc6" line="130" stmtstart="8450" stmtend="8956" sqlhandle="0x03002700bbf435679fb8e700aeac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE [dbo].[Accounts]
    WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
    SET Balance = Balance - @totalPaymentAmount, TimestampModified = GETUTCDATE()
    WHERE [ACC].AccountId = @debtorAccountId    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 39 Object Id = 1731589307]   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594582597632" dbid="39" objectname="5716a4fb-ea5f-48ff-bc69-a20036b656f3.dbo.Accounts" indexname="PK_dbo.Accounts" id="lock28450c72100" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594582597632">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process_other" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process_victim" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594582597632" dbid="39" objectname="5716a4fb-ea5f-48ff-bc69-a20036b656f3.dbo.Accounts" indexname="PK_dbo.Accounts" id="lock28ea0da7d00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594582597632">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process_victim" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process_other" mode="X" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

[image]

Comment: Don't "ABBREVIATED" give us the full code otherwise the deadlock cannot be diagnosed. Your `SELECT` is somehow taking an X lock, so there must be a further `UPDATE` later in the transaction

Comment: Do you have indices in place such that the relevant record is fetched with a seek? What do your `where` clauses look like? What happens when you remove the hints from the `update` query (where it's not needed anyway)?

Comment: @Charlieface Added full query, actually its not complex query. Yes we need X lock in order to update later in same stored procedure, and to avoid updates by any other parallel executions.

Comment: Show the full code for the sproc. Also DDL for your tables **and indexes**

Comment: @GSerg yes correct indices are in place. Please note these are 2 different stored procedures involved. We need the hint in the update query which is in uspInsertDebitCashTrans because there is no SELECT before update statement in it.

Answer (score -1):

You use too much and heavy explicit locks to do those two transactions concurrently.

Write off the "WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK)" of the queries and you will not have such deadlocks.

Of course we will be interested to have the full code involved in the transactions to help you a bit more...